# Function when scope.$last or "empty scope"

Tags: angularjs

I created a directive:

```
.directive('repeatDone', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last) {
      scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
    }
  }
})
```

to show a spinner while a list is downloaded from Firebase and rendered on screen:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:user.uid" class="item-unchecked" repeat-done="layoutDone()" ng-cloak>
```

so that the spinner disappear once the last item in the list is loaded (i.e. when *loading* is set to false):

```
$scope.loading = true;
  $scope.layoutDone = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.loading = false;
    }, 0);
  };
```

Now, this doesn't include the case in which the list is empty (i.e. anytime I create a new (empty) list. How can I add this specific scenario to the condition `if (scope.$last)`?

I already tried:

- `if (!scope || scope.$last)`
- `if (!scope.length || scope.$last)`
- `if (scope === [] || scope.$last)`

with no success.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: does `repeatDone` directive gets called while adding new record? How much time UI is taking to render new record on UI..

Comment: Hi pankajparkar, no, it's not called. As soon as you add a record the spinner disappears because the list is updated and `$scope.loading` becomes false.

Comment: I think you should use ng-click on button click and your code would be `ng-click="loading=true;layoutDone();"` this will run hide the loading in exact next digest cycle

Comment: @pankajparkar the problem is when you first open the page: if there is no item in the list `$scope.loading` stays true. When you add an item `$scope.loading` is already set to false without adding an ng-click.

Comment: @camden_kid, I have the doubt that also with your approach if there is no element in the list `last` does not exist and the condition will never be verified...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o9eSo8swzpqddu6l2CDe?p=preview).

JS

```
app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.tasks = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];

  $scope.loading = true;

  $scope.layoutDone = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      console.log("done");
      $scope.loading = false;
    }, 0);
  };
}]);

app.directive('repeatDone', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last) {
      scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
    }
  }
})

app.directive('emptyTasks', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$eval(attrs.emptyTasks);
  }
})
```

Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index" repeat-done="layoutDone()">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div ng-if="tasks.length===0" empty-tasks="layoutDone()">Hello</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The idea is to have an element that calls layoutDone if the length of **tasks** is 0:

```
<div ng-if="tasks.length===0" empty-tasks="layoutDone()">Hello</div>
```

The `ng-if` means that the div is created each time and thus calls layoutDone().

It's weird to do it like that but it follows how you were thinking of doing it. :-) You can see that "done" is written to the console if **tasks** is empty or has some elements.

Comment: This is great! And I think we are very close! The problem is that apparently while the script loads the tasks from Firebase `tasks.length` is set to 0 for a short bit. So when I load a long task list I see the spinner for a fraction of a second, then the "Hello" message and finally the list.

Comment: @MirkoG. In that case, what you could do is at the beginning put a dummy value in **tasks** that isn't a 'task', say -1, and then remove it.

Comment: Thank you... apparently the value is always set to 0 before synching with Firebase. I will keep digging, maybe there are completely different approaches to show a spinner while loading from Firebase...

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you are using

```
 $scope.loading = false
```

add

```
&& tasks && tasks.length > 0
```

so

```
<div ng-if="loading && tasks && tasks.length > 0">
I will not show if not loading, if task is null, or if there are no tasks avaiable
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Delta, it works per se, but unfortunately for some reason (or maybe it is like this by design) tasks.length is set to 0 before loading data from firebase. Therefore, the spinner shows up for a fraction of a second only...